# Better way to write fallback selector?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I've got a function that works but I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it.

I've got 5 sizes and I'm trying to get the zoom level for the current size. The catch is if the current size doesn't specify a size I want to check the other smaller sizes to see if there is one specified to use.

That is if there is no XL zoom specified, check is there is a LG to use and if not, check if there is a MD size, etc.

Currently I have a big `switch` with a bunch of `if`/`else` statements. Any cleaner way to do this that I'm missing?

```
self.updateZoom = function () {
  var defaultZoomLevel = 8;

  switch(self.getSize()) {
  case 'xs':
    if (self.xsZoom) {
      self.zoom = self.xsZoom;
    } else {
      self.zoom = defaultZoomLevel;
    }
    break;
  case 'sm':
    if (self.smZoom) {
      self.zoom = self.smZoom;
    } else if (self.xsZoom) {
      self.zoom = self.xsZoom;
    } else {
      self.zoom = defaultZoomLevel;
    }
    break;
  case 'md':
    if (self.mdZoom) {
      self.zoom = self.mdZoom;
    } else if (self.smZoom) {
      self.zoom = self.smZoom;
    } else if (self.xsZoom) {
      self.zoom = self.xsZoom;
    } else {
      self.zoom = defaultZoomLevel;
    }
    break;
  case 'lg':
    if (self.lgZoom) {
      self.zoom = self.lgZoom;
    } else if (self.mdZoom) {
      self.zoom = self.mdZoom;
    } else if (self.smZoom) {
      self.zoom = self.smZoom;
    } else if (self.xsZoom) {
      self.zoom = self.xsZoom;
    } else {
      self.zoom = defaultZoomLevel;
    }
    break;
  case 'xl':
    if (self.xlZoom) {
      self.zoom = self.xlZoom;
    } else if (self.lgZoom) {
      self.zoom = self.lgZoom;
    } else if (self.mdZoom) {
      self.zoom = self.mdZoom;
    } else if (self.smZoom) {
      self.zoom = self.smZoom;
    } else if (self.xsZoom) {
      self.zoom = self.xsZoom;
    } else {
      self.zoom = defaultZoomLevel;
    }
    break;
  default:
    self.zoom = defaultZoomLevel;
  }

  self.zoom = parseInt(self.zoom);
}
```

Comment: instead of the switch, you could use only case xl. as far as i can see, this would result in the same zoomlevels than used with the switch case.

Comment: `self.zoom = self.xsZoom || defaultZoomLevel;`

Answer (score 1):

let's call it "progressive enhancement":

we start with the smallest and proceed until we reach size returned by `self.getSize()`

```
['xs', 'sm', 'md', 'lg', 'xl'].forEach(function(size){
    if(self[size + 'Zoom']){
        self.zoom = self[size + 'Zoom'];
    }

    if(size == self.getSize()){
        return false;
    }
});
```

EDIT: as there is no way to break inside built-in forEach you could try ES6 way:

```
['xs', 'sm', 'md', 'lg', 'xl'].some(function(size){
    if(self[size + 'Zoom']){
        self.zoom = self[size + 'Zoom'];
    }

    return size == self.getSize();
});
```

or @Glufu 's answer

Comment: why do you return false?

Comment: return false means "break" in jQuery for-each-loop

Comment: and return true would not break?

Comment: sorry, my bad... built-in forEach doesn't break on return false :(

Comment: retun true means "continue"

Answer (score 1):

The other way around of @pwolaq 's version with pure JS:

```
// init variables
var steps = ['xl', 'lg', 'md', 'sm', 'xs'];
var i = steps.indexOf(self.getSize());

// check borders
i = (i == -1) ? steps.length-1 : i;
// set default zoom
self.zoom = self.xsZoom;

// "search" best zoom
for(; i<steps.length; i++){
  if(self[steps[i] + 'Zoom']){
    self.zoom = self[steps[i]+'Zoom'];
    break;
  }
}
```

if `self.getSize()` is `'lg'` it will try first `self.lgZoom`. if it doesn't succeed it will try `self.mdZoom` and then `self.smZoom` and so on.

Comment: how about indexOf returning -1?

Comment: you should check the condition before entering the loop - this way it will be checked on every iteration, not to mention that it will not set zoom to defaultZoomLevel variable value